# How to run Cypress Parallelization on the Bitbucket?

Tags: cypress, bitbucket-pipelines

How to run Cypress Parallelization on the Bitbucket ?
I have such bitbucket-pipelines.yml

```
e2e: &e2e
  name: E2E tests
  caches:
    - node
    - cypress
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm run start:ci
  artifacts:
    # store any generates images and videos as artifacts
    - cypress/videos/**/*.mp4
    - cypress/screenshots/**/*.png

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: 'E2E tests'
        caches:
          - npm
          - cypress
          - node
        script:
          - npm install
        artifacts:
          - build/**
    - parallel:
      # run N steps in parallel
      - step:
          <<: *e2e
      - step:
          <<: *e2e
      - step:
          <<: *e2e
```

package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "profile",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "cypress open",
    "start:ci": "cypress run --record --parallel --ci-build-id $BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER --key $CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY --record"
  },
```

cypress.config.js

```
module.exports = defineConfig({
  viewportWidth: 1920,
  viewportHeight: 1080,
  defaultCommandTimeout: 6000,
  hideXHRInCommandLog: true,
  retries: 1,
  e2e: {
    // We've imported your old cypress plugins here.
    // You may want to clean this up later by importing these.
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      return require('./cypress/plugins/index.js')(on, config)
    },
    baseUrl: 'https://frontend.test.novoconnect.org/',
  },
})
```

Screenshot from Bitbucket pipeline:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1p8n.png)
It runs only one job without Parallelization  tests, as you can see on the screenshot

To fix bitbucket file